# react native app crashes when tf.ready called

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

I followed all instructions to install @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native given at
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native/v/0.3.0

this is my app.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';


import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default () => {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
      await tf.ready()
      setReady(true)
    }
    load()
  })
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={'dark-content'} />
      <View>
        <Text>hello</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

App crashes when tf.ready() is called. no error is logged in console.
If i comment tf.ready() everything works fine. am i doing something wrong?

This is my package.json file

[image of package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cyRd.png)
How do i test if this package is installed correctly?
any help from your side will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when running my app with expo on an android device, what solved it for me was setting the backend with :

```
await tf.setBackend('cpu');
```

before

```
tf.ready();
```

It might solve your problem as well